# SQL inner join two tables with 2 match on right

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables like this:
[image]

I want to select `In` and `Out` values from log details where `id=1` in log table.
I tried this for `In` value:

```
SELECT Log.Time, LogDetail.Value
FROM Log where ID=1
INNER JOIN LogDetail
ON Log.ID=LogDetail.ID where Name="In";
```

Is this a true query?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will try to run this query - you will see it can't be executed. The reason is two `where` statements it contains.

Query can contain only one `where` statement in most DBMS (while this statement can contain multiple conditions joined together by logical operators).

Also it is better to use table aliases - this makes query more readable and prevents possible ambiguities.

So your query should look like:

```
select L.Time, LD.Value
from Log as L
    inner join LogDetail as LD on L.ID=LD.ID 
where L.ID=1 and LD.Name="In"
```